# Entity Framework 6 in asp.net mvc 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 in my project and using database first approach to create edmx files in project. However my Stored procedures which exist in db when created as classed in code, the naming is followed by _Result which i do not want. Is there a way i can over ride this _Result suffix to my custom suffix.

Comment: Please check the following link
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/create-dbcontext-in-entity-framework5.aspx

Comment: Sure you can do this but, I don't know about the automatic process but if you want to change a specific procedure then it can be done by using model browser

Comment: Using model browser i have to manually update the names, but i want to update this suffix in some configurations of EF so that this is not created at first place, because edmx is updated very frequently so i have to rename the SPs each time to remove under score from their name

Comment: Sorry but i could not find an answer to my query on this link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/create-dbcontext-in-entity-framework5.aspx